# Is it possible to change the default: option in Yeoman depending on a previous answer?

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

I'm curious if it's possible to change the default message of a prompt depending on what the user selected from a previous prompt.

Right now my first prompt is just a list where the user selects one option and is asked a few other questions. Note that these two run in two different generators

```
YeomanGenerator.prototype.askForThings = function askForThings() {
  var cb = this.async();
  var prompts = [{
    name: 'questionOne',
    type: 'list',
    message: 'Message, message?',
    choices: ['optionOne', 'optionTwo', 'optionThree', 'optionFour', 'optionFive', 'optionSix', 'None'],
    filter: function(value) { 
      return value.toLowerCase(); 
    }
  }
```

Then, in the next section the user is asked in which directory to place this. However, I'm wondering if it's possible to change the default location depending on what the user selected in `questionOne`. Right now the `default` option just comes out empty.

```
YeomanGenerator.prototype.askForMoreThings = function askForMoreThings() {
  var cb = this.async();

  var questionOne = this.questionOne;

    {
      name: 'questionOneDirectory',
      message: 'Question question',
      default: function(default) {
        if (this.questionOne === 'optionOne') {
          this.default("'/directory/_one'");
        }
        else if (this.questionOne === 'optionTwo') {
          this.default("'/directory/_two'");
        }
        { 
          //etc 
        }
      },
      filter: function(value) { return value.split('/').pop(); },
      when: function() {
        return questionOne;
      },
```

Is it even possible to change the default message here? It's just a minor things but I'm wondering if it's at all possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a generic solution for those who search the answer to the question topic. `default` property accepts a function and passes an object with all previous answers to it. Use that object to generate defaults in runtime:

```js
this.prompt([{
  name: 'title',
  message: 'Your title?',
  default: 'Mr.'
}, {
  name: 'name',
  message: 'Your name?',
  default: function(answers) {
    return answers.title + ' Smith';
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I actually figured it out on my own. I had to declare a variable `questionOneDefaultDirectory` and then run the if/else if right underneath and then call that variable from the prompt. The code looks like this now:

```
YeomanGenerator.prototype.askForThings = function askForThings() {
  var cb = this.async();
  var prompts = [{
    name: 'questionOne',
    type: 'list',
    message: 'Message, message?',
    choices: ['optionOne', 'optionTwo', 'optionThree', 'optionFour', 'optionFive', 'optionSix', 'None']
  }
```

And then the last part.

```
YeomanGenerator.prototype.askForMoreThings = function askForMoreThings() {
  var questionOne = this.questionOne;
  var cb = this.async();

  var questionOneDefaultDirectory;

  if (this.questionOne === 'optionOne') {
    questionOneDefaultDirectory = '/directory/_one'
  }
  else if (this.questionOne === 'optionTwo') {
    questionOneDefaultDirectory = '/directory/_two'
  }
  { 
    //etc 
  }

    this.prompt([{
      name: 'questionOneDirectory',
      message: 'Question question',
      default: questionOneDefaultDirectory,
      filter: function(value) { return value.split('/').pop(); },
      when: function() {
        return questionOne;
      }
    }], function (etcetc) {
      // etc
    }
```

Now, depending on what is selected during the first question the default directory will change depending on what was answered.